# how to gsub awk in unix with binary data

Tags: bash, unix, awk

How do I gsub awk a file that contains binary characters like "<85>" this case would make my program crash.

I have code like this using cat

```
cat $filename | awk '{gsub("<85>",RS);print}' > somedir/sometxtfile.txt
```

this wouldn't work on files which contains binary characters like this file

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *01*157322272      *ZZ*00116520M      *160907*1830*^*00403*000005354*0*P*><85>GS*PO*157322272*00116520M*20160907*1830*000005354*X*004030VICS<85>ST*850*0001<85>BEG*00*RE*7570006859**20160907<85>CUR*BY*USD<85>REF*IA*5164<85>REF*DP*595*ELECTRONICS             F<85>PER*BD*JILL MAYNARD<85>ITD*******45<85>DTM*001*20160919<85>DTM*037*20160912<85>N1*ST**92*51<85>PO1*1*14*EA*29.38*QT*UP*753048155606*VA*T54281E4BLK/GRY*IT*T54281E4*IN*12693802*BO*Orange*IZ*NO SIZE<85>CTP*RS*RES*59.99<85>PID*F****2015IMSLK5/ORANG/NSIZE/NDIMN<85>PO4*1<85>SDQ*EA*92*105*1*157*1*186*1*234*1*283*1*414*2*426*1*464*1*626*1*672*1<85>SDQ*EA*92*1012*1*1030*1*1083*1<85>PO1*2*14*EA*23.66*QT*UP*753048179756*VA*T40941E4*IT*T40941E4*IN*12693812*BO*Grey*IZ*NO SIZE<85>CTP*RS*RES*49.99<85>PID*F****2015EXPFUL/GREY/NSIZE/NDIMN<85>PO4*1<85>SDQ*EA*
```

Comment: You might first explain what you're trying to do, and why wouldn't it work?

Comment: we don't need a record that is a mile wide, can't you illustrate the problem in a 30 char record? Good luck.

Comment: Hmm, I was playing around with this and if I `gawk 'BEGIN {printf "%c" ORS , "\x41"}'` I get an `A` as expected but if I `awk 'BEGIN {printf "%c" ORS , "\x85"}'` I get `gawk: cmd. line:1: fatal: format_tree: obuf: can't allocate 34359738368 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)`. `mawk` gives me a `�` at least.

Comment: Binary files are not suitable to be parsed by `awk` or any other text tool.

Comment: That's not binary in the sense, it's some extended ascii character.

Comment: "Binary files are not suitable to be parsed by awk or any other text tool." ….. says who ? i've even gotten gawk in unicode multi-byte mode to do byte-exact lengthB( ), reverse revB( ), substrB( ) and ordB( ) …. without ever spitting out that error message about "invalid multibyte character", nor needing to artificially supress that error message either.

Answer (score 2):

Let's create that character:

`$ awk 'BEGIN {print "A \x85 B"}'  > foo`

And view it with `less` for example:

```
$ less foo
A <85> B
foo (END)
```

And remove it:

```
$ awk 'sub(/\x85/,"X")' foo
A X B
```